# Get information from stream 1

Tags: c, bash

I have to do a little project for my school and I would like to have some help for a little problem.

For this project I have to recreate a command interpreter like bash/shell without advanced option like redirection or pipe for now.
I finished it and i decided to do a little more. I created a prompt like this :

```
"my_login" ~/home/"my_login"/rendu/PSU_2014_minishell1 $
```

But when i do "cd" my prompt needs to change , problem is I can't refresh it because i took the environment variable PWD.
And to complicate a little more the work, i can't use every systems call I should use only:

- `opendir`
- `readdir`
- `closedir`
- `malloc`
- `free`
- `exit`
- `chdir`
- `fork`
- `stat`
- `lstat`
- `fstat`
- `open`
- `close`
- `read`
- `write`
- `execve`
- `access`
- `wait`
- `waitpid`
- `wait3`
- `wait4`
- `signal`
- `kill`

I have an idea but I don't know how to do it. I thought I can execute the binairy "/bin/pwd" to have my location , but I don't how how to get this information after execute it, have you any idea?

Thanks !

And sorry for my bad english, I am French.

Comment: Are you sure `getcwd()` is not in the list?

Comment: Yes I am sure i'm not allowed to use other functions that these ones

Comment: Do you know what directory you start in?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Yes, i take the information from the environnement variable PWD

Comment: Do you know what directory the user wants to change to?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams not the exact path. The user can do for exemple cd ../../ or cd ~/work. It will work for chdir but i can't use this information to change my prompt.

Comment: The first is text processing. The second is reading `$HOME`.